# The international club of a school has 105 members, many of whom speak multiple languages.

Tags: probability

[image: The international club of a school has 105 members, many of whom speak multiple languages. The most commonly spoken languages in the club are English, Korean, and Chinese. Use the Venn diagram below to determine the probability of selecting students who]

> The international club of a school has 105 members, many of whom speak multiple languages. The most commonly spoken languages in the club are English, Korean, and Chinese. Use the Venn diagram below to determine the probability of selecting students who:

a. Does not speak English.

In notation, we can say,

$P(K\cup C\cup E - E) = \frac{n(K\cup C\cup E - E)}{total  no.  of  students}$

$n(K\cup C\cup E) - n(E) = 101 - 89 = 12$

$P(K\cup C\cup E - E) = \frac{12}{105} = \frac{4}{35}$

The probability that does not speak English is $\frac{4}{35}$

edit:

a. Does not speak English.

In notation, we can say,

$P(K\cup C\cup E - E + (K\cup C\cup E)')$

$= \frac{n(K\cup C\cup E) - n(E) + n(K\cup C\cup E)'}{total  no.  of  students}$

$= \frac{101 - 89 + 4}{105} = \frac{16}{105}$

Answer for (a) is $\frac{16}{105}$

thanks Eric for what I missed..

b. Speaks English given that he/she speaks Chinese.

$P(E|C) = \frac{n(E\cap C)}{n(C)}$

$n(E\cap C) = 8 + 13 = 21$

$n(C) = 2 + 3 + 8 + 13 = 26$

$P(E|C) = \frac{21}{26}$

c. Speaks Korean and English but not Chinese.

In notation,

$P(K\cap E - K\cap E\cap C) = \frac{n(K\cap E - K\cap E\cap C)}{total no. of students}$

$n(K\cap E) - n(K\cap E\cap C) = (33 + 8) - (8) = 33$

$P(K\cap E - K\cap E\cap C) = \frac{33}{105} = \frac{11}{35}$

d. Speaks Korean given that he/she speaks English.

$P(K|E) =  \frac{n(K\cap E)}{n(E)}$

$P(K|E) = \frac{33 + 8}{89} = \frac{41}{89}$

Comment: Those answers look plausible

Comment: There are $105$ people. You missed the $4$ in the bottom left corner when considering how many don’t speak English.